# Question titles on history tab of recent reviews are too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review-history

- Visit /review
- Click "recent reviews" link for any queue
- Click the "history" tab
- Question titles are too big. Deleted question titles don't have this problem.
- Observed on SO, MSE, and ELL; CV and SE queues; didn't bother to check elsewhere
- Observed with latest Firefox (35.0.1) on Ubuntu 14.04
- I'm using NoSquint 2.1.9 with a zoom setting of 120%; disabling it and/or restoring zoom to 100% doesn't fix the issue (text size shrinks but is still mismatched)
- Font size is set to a fixed 18px in the CSS (thanks Shadow Wizard)
- It's pretty distracting; I want to look at the review results, not click through to the question
- I'm a serial rejector
- Bulletted list

[image]

Comment: Yikes! No header, just explicit CSS rule setting the font size to fixed 18px (!)

Comment: Good catch. We adjusted the font size on the question titles.

Answer (score 1):

As Kurtis said, this should be fixed in production.